# Iterating over a list of tuples and inside tuples using a for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, nested-loops

Just wondering how to iterate over a list of tuples and also iterate through the items inside the tuples at the same time.

```
# I am able iterate over a list of tuples like this,
fruit_list = [('banana','apple','mango'),('strawberry', 'blueberry','raspberry')]
for fruit_tup in fruit_list:
    print(fruit_tup)

#output:
#('banana', 'apple', 'mango')
#('strawberry', 'blueberry', 'raspberry')

# Iterate through the items inside the tuples as so,
for (item1,item2,item3) in fruit_list:
    print(item1,item2,item3)

#output:
#banana apple mango
#strawberry blueberry raspberry

# This is incorrect but I tried to iterate over the tuples and the items inside the tuples as so
for fruit_tup,(item1,item2,item3) in fruit_list:
    print(fruit_tup,item1,item2,item3)

#required output:
#('banana', 'apple', 'mango') banana apple mango
#('strawberry', 'blueberry', 'raspberry') strawberry blueberry raspberry
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What if you have 3, 4, or N tuples in the list? What would you like to iterate on then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *nested* loop:

```
fruit_list = [('banana','apple','mango'),('strawberry', 'blueberry','raspberry')]
for fruit_tup in fruit_list:
    for fruit in fruit_tup:
        print(fruit, end=' ') # no newline but a single space
    print() # now do a newline
```

Prints:

```
banana apple mango
strawberry blueberry raspberry
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the bellow:

```py
for lst in fruit_list:
    for fruit in lst:
        print(fruit, end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

To create a list of your outputs:

```
lst = [('banana','apple','mango'),('strawberry', 'blueberry','raspberry')]
output = [" ".join(tupel) for tupel in lst]
```

If you directly want to print them:

```
[print(" ".join(tupel)) for tupel in lst]
```

If you want to loop through the tupels and the list at the same time:

```
output = [fruit for tupel in lst for fruit in tupel]
```

Comment: printing in list comprehension is not advised.

Comment: List compheresion was to made to create a list.

Comment: Because it is very anti-Pythonic. See: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)